# Create new column and fill the nearby rows within a certain time interval with the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have minute level time series data with two columns DateTime and Flag. I want to create a third column (InTimeWindow) using the following logic:
Whenever the flag is 1, I want to set the rows of the third column within +/- 2 minutes as 1 otherwise keep the third column as zero. Any ideas how this can be accomplished..? Any help would be appreciated.

```
DateTime    Flag    InTimeWindow
1/1/18 12:00 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:01 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:02 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:03 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:04 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:05 AM 1   1
1/1/18 12:06 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:07 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:08 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:09 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:10 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:11 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:12 AM 1   1
1/1/18 12:13 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:14 AM 0   1
1/1/18 12:15 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:16 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:17 AM 0   0
1/1/18 12:18 AM 0   0
```

Also, attached is the picture with sample data:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18vMj.png)

Comment: Is your DateTime always increasing by 1 minute?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. DateTime always increasing by a minute..any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to iterate over your rows and look at the flag column. If you see a flag == 0 you set the inTimeWindow at this index = 1. If you see a flag == 1 you set a slice starting at index-2:index+2 = 1. You just need to take care of the edge cases at the start row and the end row.